# How to check type depends another parameter type?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum:

```
export declare enum TemplateFill {
     Trellis = "Trellis",
     Divot = "Divot"
}
```

And function description:

```
export declare function FactoryTemplateFill (type: TemplateFill, config: Config): HTMLCanvasElement | undefined;
```

How to make it so that TS checks, depending on the passed `TemplateFill`, the contents of the `config: Config`, For example, if it is Divot, then the required field is `{padding: number}` in the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a type that contains what maps to what. Something like:

```
interface TemplateFillConfig {
  [TemplateFill.Trellis]: { margin: number }
  [TemplateFill.Divot]: { padding: number }
}
```

Then you need to make your function generic so that it can accept a subtype of `TemplateFill` and infer the correct config from it.

```
export declare function FactoryTemplateFill<T extends TemplateFill>(
  type: T,
  config: TemplateFillConfig[T]
): HTMLCanvasElement | undefined;
```

Which can be used like this:

```
// Good
FactoryTemplateFill(TemplateFill.Trellis, { margin: 123 })
FactoryTemplateFill(TemplateFill.Divot, { padding: 456 })

// Bad
FactoryTemplateFill(TemplateFill.Trellis, { huh: 987 })
FactoryTemplateFill(TemplateFill.Divot, { unknownProp: 111 })
```

[Working Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=6#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDsAdgVwFs4AVYQsDGYAMQEtVU4BvAKDg45K0boGc4AXjgAibsF58RAGnac4AEToA3CPGEilqmCNYBfVqzq5qUAGbpk2MhSq0GqAMIRcZugHMWcgNo3K6anpGADpxSQBdAC4WOEJMd2NogkIAI2AoOAMOX3J-QIdgrTUomLB0BARjdySiNIyDA1ZQSFhEFAwsODN8XGQYOhc4GksYaABPPzsg1AAeEhwQalwEAUmA+0YAPgAKORgxsGBoklkOZBc3atJcqYdnVw9fcNYASmiACRIAWQAZR3RcMp0HwAKKoch4eAAHzgPSQblwwAQAG5DKwAPTouAAcQgEAQrGGfXGa3yjG2pI2qFCPFQ-GkMTiUASuGiAEYAEwAZkyL0JIxJN3W0wpQrJ1KKMAZzDgZQqVWiABYAKwANl5hkxcAAQuV+cSoBMxVTRbZhQUwnS+NK4AALfC26IATgAHAB2DVE0aGyki30FSU2noAa1wEAA7rgAApQCBgdlstm8oA)

Comment: Thank you it is better

Answer (score 0):

That is solution I need:

```
function FactoryTemplateFill<TemplateType, ConfigType extends keyof TemplateType>(type: TemplateType, config: ConfigType): HTMLCanvasElement | undefined {
    return undefined;
}
```